# How to enable Authentication/Authorization for Azure function App python for source system

Tags: authentication, azure-functions

I have created Azure function app python. We have source system Guidewire which calls this Azure function app. We are planning to add security level to function app so that any system connecting to function app need to authenticate and authorize. Please let me know how to enable this and how to perform authentication/authorization function app(python).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions lets you access your function endpoints in different authorization scopes like ***System*** level, ***admin*** level, ***user*** level and ***anonymous*** level.

While function keys can help prevent unauthorized access, the only way to completely secure your function endpoints is to use affirmative authentication for all clients who visit your functions. You can then make authorization decisions based on identity.

By providing out-of-the-box authentication with federated identity providers, the ***built-in authentication functionality*** for App Service and ***Azure Functions*** can save you time and effort, allowing you to focus on the rest of your application.

[image]

When you enable ***authentication*** and ***authorization*** with one of these providers, ***its sign-in endpoint is available for user authentication and for validation of authentication tokens from the provider***. You can provide your users with any number of these sign-in options.

***Azure Functions*** uses Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) as the default identity and access management service.

Please refer the [what are the built-in authentications provided and customization details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization), [authorization scope of azure functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/security-concepts#function-access-keys) and [azure function security system in base line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/benchmark/azure/baselines/functions-security-baseline#identity-management) for detailed information.

Comment: Thanks Hari, once authentication enabled in Azure function, is there any validataions to be done for incomming client message to authenticate from function app(python). Can you give steps please.

Comment: Hello @SSR - Please find the incoming client messages validation in azure function from this [article](https://www.tomfaltesek.com/azure-functions-input-validation/) as author is written contact form in the azure function and validating the input client messages/values using ***if-block*** statements which is old solution and implemented new validation using open source library called ***FluentValidation Library***. And It's in C# and if possible, give a try in python with the same logic.

Comment: If any validation of incoming client messages use case available for Azure Functions (Python Stack) available, will update here.

Comment: Hello @SSR - there is incoming values code validation using Twilio in Azure Function (Python Stack), please checkout this [article](https://www.twilio.com/blog/validate-phone-numbers-python-azure-functions-twilio) where author has done validation to the contact number using Twilio in Azure Functions (python)

Comment: Thanks @HarisKrishnaRajoli for response its helpful. we are trying to use client certificate now.