# How to add Basic Auth for Azure HttpTrigger Java Function

Tags: java, azure-functions, azure-authentication, azure-java-sdk, azure-http-trigger

I have created a sample Azure HTTP Trigger Java Function using Visual Studio Code and Deployed it to Azure Function App.  Now it is Working Fine in Postman without authorization

**Postman Basic Auth Screenshot**

[image]

```
package com.function;

import com.microsoft.azure.functions.ExecutionContext;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpMethod;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpRequestMessage;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpResponseMessage;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpStatus;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.AuthorizationLevel;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.FunctionName;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.HttpTrigger;

import java.util.Optional;

/**
 * Azure Functions with HTTP Trigger.
 */
public class Function {
    /**
     * This function listens at endpoint "/api/HttpExample". Two ways to invoke it using "curl" command in bash:
     * 1. curl -d "HTTP Body" {your host}/api/HttpExample
     * 2. curl "{your host}/api/HttpExample?name=HTTP%20Query"
     */
    @FunctionName("HttpExample")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(
            @HttpTrigger(
                name = "req",
                methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST},
                authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)
                HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

        // Parse query parameter
        final String query = request.getQueryParameters().get("name");
        final String name = request.getBody().orElse(query);

  

          if (name == null) {
                return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body").build();
            }

     else {
                    return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Hello, " + name).build();
        
                }
        }
    }
```

Now I need to add basic auth to that Function.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

- For Authorization to your function app, one of the methods you can use is the Authorization Level keys appending at the end of the Function URL.*

[image]

- You can find the Host Keys and System Keys at the App Keys in Azure Function App.

[image]

Refer to this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/security-concepts?tabs=v4#authenticationauthorization) and this SO [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70444686/16630138) for more information on configuring the Authentication and Authorization for securing the Azure Functions.

Comment: Hi pravalika Thanks! Already Iam using OAuth But, my clients asking only basic auth.... Please help

Comment: Hi Pravalika for Your solution can I change anything in code level?